# Recaptcha v3 a lot of false positives

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

We have implemented google recaptcha v3 on a branch and are testing it thoroughly before releasing it onto prod.

While testing, we have detected that it recognizes real humans as bots in about 22% of cases... which is way too much false positives than what is acceptable.

Is this a know issue, that v3 has a lot of false positives?

What can we do about that / what are the best practices?

Is there a way to test if it recognizes real bots without writing a bot ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

reCaptchav3 returns a score between 1.0 and 0.0 depending on how **probable** the interaction is coming from a bot. Also it learns to detect non-human interactions by studying real traffic on your website. This means it gets better at detection over time and very soon after staging is bound to have a bunch of false positives.

You can move it to prod with a threshold you consider an interaction to be a bot, lower than it is now and move that up as reCaptcha learns to distinguish real and bot traffic.

As for testing, writing your own bots seems the best way to go IMO

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, it's normal to get weird results when you first integrate reCAPTCHA V3.

Google kind of explains why this is the case in their documentation:

[From Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#interpreting_the_score):

> reCAPTCHA learns by seeing real traffic on your site. For this reason,
> scores in a staging environment or soon after implementing may differ
> from production.

Basically, google needs to learn how a normal user behaves on your website before it can start giving accurate scores.  But when you first release V3, Google doesn't have enough data to build an accurate model for your site yet.  Furthermore, the model for your staging env will differ from your production environment if the kind/frequency of traffic that your staging env is getting is different then prod (which I'm assuming is the case most of the time).

If you're concern about the initial inaccurate scores while Google is building a model for your site, you can integrate [both V2 and V3 onto your site](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#can-i-run-recaptcha-v2-and-v3-on-the-same-page).  Basically with this method, you will only validate V2 on your backend but in your front end code, you will be submitting both V2 and V3 reCaptcha at the same time on submit (V3 will be summited using the AJAX call `grecaptcha.execute('v3_site_key', {action: 'homepage'})` ).  This way Google can start building a V3 model for your site and when you're ready to move permanently to V3, google reCaptcha will start giving you accurate scores from the get-go.